# intermittent 'unable to start debugging on the web server...' in VS2012

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

There are a number of questions on stackoverflow relating to being 'unable to start debugging on the web server...' but I have variation of this problem: it's intermittent and it goes away if I restart VS2012.  This would tend to indicate that some process or other is locking up another process, or a file is locked, etc, etc by *devenv.exe* (ie VS2012) and closing VS unlocks the file/process/whatever.

The Visual Studio solution contains a number of MVC4 websites that use IIS running on my 64-bit Windows 7 development computer.  All the website, domain model and test projects in this VS solution are configured for .NET 4.5. *MvcBuildViews* is set to true in the CS project file.

I've tried recycling the IIS application pool for the start-up project, stopping and starting the IIS site, resetting IIS completely,  to no avail. I have a suspicion the error message may actually be incorrect, but it's only a suspicion.  Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I've seen this too, today in fact, an admin iisreset and clean solution did the trick but that's not an answer, just thought I'd back up your question.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the event logs when this occurs?

Comment: I hadn't thought to look there, but having done so I find: '1002 (101) The program devenv.exe version 11.0.51106.1 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed' and '1000 (100) Faulting application name: WebBrowserServer.exe, version: 1.0.30710.0'.  Also the Web Farm service is issuing occasional faults - this is something that I installed years ago to try out and promptly forgot about.  I've now removed that.  I'll see if there is any improvement.